# map(item) function can't pass "item" to JSX component as props after implementing redux in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement redux in my react application. I have created 4 actions so far to manage my applications "items". The first three; a GET_ITEMS, DELETE_ITEM, and ADD_ITEM work perfectly and have meshed easily with my existing react application. The fourth "TOGGLE_ITEM" actually functions and toggle the items but somehow broke my existing react component. I get an "item" undefined error in my Items.js file. Here is the code, the lines with asterisks are of high importance:

1. Root component = Musiclist.js:

```
class MusicList extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getItems();
        *console.log(this.props.item.items)*
        // Console log returns the proper items array that gets passed down below to the Items component
    }

    toggle = (id) => {
        *this.props.toggleItem(id)*
        // Pings the item reducer and executes the toggle function, which functions properly
    }

    delItem = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteItem(id)
    }

    addItem = (url) => {
        this.props.addItem(url)
    }

    render() {

        *const { items } = this.props.item*
        // Same as saying this.props.item.items

        return (
            
            <div>

                <AddItem addItem={this.addItem}/>

                *<Items items = {items} toggle = {this.toggle} delItem = {this.delItem} />*
                // Takes in the array items as a prop and the function toggle() as a prop

            </div>

        )
        
    }

}

MusicList.propTypes = {
    getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired, 
    addItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    toggleItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    item: state.item
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItems, deleteItem, addItem, toggleItem})(MusicList);
```

Reducer = itemReducer.js:

This seems to work perfectly and does as it's supposed to. I also don't see any apparent reason this would affect the Items component so it's likely a red hearing... But I only started having problems after implementing it.

```
case TOGGLE_ITEM:
   return {
      items: state.items.map(item => {
         if(item.id === action.payload) {
            item.isOpen = !item.isOpen
         }
      })
   }
```

Problem component = Items.js:

The component throwing the error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Item from "./Item";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Items extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // Console logs the same array as the one in MusicList.js
        *console.log(this.props.items)*
        this.props.items.map((item) => (
            // Console logs as it's supposed to, maps the items and prints them, no "item undefined" error
            console.log(item)
        ))
    }
    
    render() {

        return this.props.items.map((item) => (

            <div>

                // "item" is undefined on this line despite the map function defining it above. 
                // I did not change any code here when implementing redux, yet there was no error before redux.
                *<Item key = {item.id} item = {item} toggle = {this.props.toggle} delItem = {this.props.delItem} isOpen = {item.isOpen}/>*

            </div>

            ));
    }
}

// PropTypes
Items.propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default Items;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The correct toggle update should also copy any existing state and return a new item object reference in the mapping, i.e. `return { ...state, item: state.items.map(item => item.id === action.payload ? { ...item, isOpen: !item.isOpen } : item), }`. Since you only have issue after implementing `TOGGLE_ITEM` is it safe to assume the UI code is fine until you try and toggle an item? Can you provide a more complete code example and reproduction steps? A *running* codesandbox would be really helpful so we can live debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map function in reducer will need a return statement

```
case TOGGLE_ITEM:
   return {
      ...state,
      items: state.items.map(item => {
         if(item.id === action.payload) {
            item.isOpen = !item.isOpen
         }
         return item;
      })
   }
```

This will solve the issue. And always spread state and then add comma and then the changed key value pairs

Comment: The "return item" part solved it. But what is the purpose of returning the state with "...state"?

Comment: When you use `...state`(ES6 object destructuring, you can use Object.assign as well) in return of reducer function, then it creates an object with all the data which is in that reducer, and then the mentioned keys get added/replaced to that object. this way your other data is intact, but if you don't use `...state` then your reducer contains only the object with the mentioned key value pairs.
Check out this doc https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions

Answer (score 1):

Is it well written in your app? That line of code should be:

```
<Item key={item.id} item={item} toggle={this.props.toggle} delItem={this.props.delItem} isOpen={item.isOpen}/>
```

No whitespace should be between the prop and the actual value

Comment: Sadly this did not work, I'm pretty sure the white space thing is either cosmetic or the compiler fixes it.